# AngularJS: difference between injection parameter and $injector

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Just like this guy [posted here](http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/thoughts/post.cfm/angular-material-design-mdtoast-and-httpinterceptors), I was using $md-toast service from Angular Material to notify users when API calls return errors. I got "Circular dependency found" and found the (previously quoted) article.

What's the difference between

```
  .factory('toastHttpInterceptor', function ($mdToast) {
    return {
      responseError: function(response) {
        $mdToast.showSimple('Error');
      }
    };
  });
```

and

```
  .factory('toastHttpInterceptor', function ($injector) {
    return {
      responseError: function(response) {
        var $mdToast = $injector.get('$mdToast');
        $mdToast.showSimple('Error');
      }
    };
  });
```

?? How does the second one remove the "Circular dependency found" problem?

Comment: I think that in the second case the dependencies check are perform after angular boots. At runtime like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one removes the circular dependency because **when loading the module**, calls to factory are resolved first, so the module understands:

```
toastHttpInterceptor <- injector
```

while directly or indirectly, your mdToast will have this dependency path:

```
mdToast <- ... <- toastHttpInterceptor
```

But when that code is called on its own, the mdToast is resolved **lazily**. You get the reference **lazily** so you can use it, and it is not obtained until you need it, in contrast to obtain it in definition time.

So:

1. When loading, avoid having a circular path on the injection definition. Such injection will be processed as a whole, and may fail.
2. The fix involves that you know `$mdToast` will exist, although not specified as dependence (since you can't), and asks it in the code execution (which will be **after** initialization; module and its parts are already loaded).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. And what is more appropriate ? Is it some kind of "don't use $injector until you really need it" ?

Comment: The given solution you used is appropriate.